# Why when a Line constructor is called are some of the values being initialized as NaN?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6, constructor, prototypal-inheritance

I'm calling a Line constructor with 2 arguments (both points), start and end. Points have x and y properties. Both constructors work most of the time (Point all of the time afaik) but when I call Line.getPerpendicular (which returns a new Line), even though the correct values are being passed into the Line constructor, it's end point values are both NaN.

I isolated the points in the Line constructor and the end point initially has values but when I set this.end = endPoint, this.end is NaN for x and y.

Creating the points directly instead of first assigning them to values doesn't help.

The Line constructor works most of the time.

```
function line(start, end) {
  console.log({ start, end });
  // { start: point { x: 97, y: 299 }, end: point { x: 223, y: 341 } }
  /* 
  this.start = start;
  this.end = end;
  Originally I thought this might be the problem, like I was
  passing in end by reference and then it was being gc'd
  */
  const ex = end.x;
  const ey = end.y;
  const endP = Point(ex, ey);
  console.log("END POINT", endP); // point { x: 223, y: 341 }
                                  // the Point is definitely constructed
                                  // correctly.
  this.start = Point(start.x, start.y);
  this.end = endP;

  console.log(this);
  // line { start: point { x: 97, y: 299 }, end: point { x: NaN, y: NaN } }

}
```

You can reproduce by cloning https://github.com/Sjbrimley26/geometry, running npm i, and then npm run build. Then just open the built html file and check out the console.

// Edit
Here's the getPerpendicular function that's apparently causing the bug because the Line constructor works otherwise, although I don't understand why because Line is because called with the correct point values.

```
line.prototype.getPerpendicular = function() {
  const { slope, length, center } = this;
  const inv = -1 * divide(1)(slope);
  const { x, y } = center;
  const b = subtract(y)(inv * x);

  const x0 = x - Math.floor(length);
  const y0 = x0 * inv + b;
  const x1 = x + Math.floor(length);
  const y1 = x1 * inv + b;
  console.log({ x0, y0, x1, y1 });
  const start = Point(x0, y0);
  const end = Point(x1, y1);
  console.log({ start, end });
  return Line(start, end);

 /*
  This doesn't work either
  return Line(
    Point(
      x - Math.floor(length), 
      (x- Math.floor(length)) * inv + b
    ),
    Point(
      x + Math.floor(length),
      (x + Math.floor(length)) * inv + b
    )
  );
  */
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be "new Point()" for each point creation?

Comment: If you freeze it – `this.end = Object.freeze(endP);` – does anything throw? That would be something mutating your end point, which you also have to look at (if intended) or fix (if not intended). Make sure all files are in strict mode before doing that test or it’ll just fail silently.

Comment: Point is just a wrapper function that creates a new point (lowercase).

Comment: Tried switching it to strict mode and freezing the endP but it doesn't seem to have affected anything.

Comment: All your files have to be in strict mode, not just this one. Alternatively, there’s the more complicated `this.end = new Proxy(endP, {set() { throw new Error('no') }});`, which should throw even in sloppy mode.

Comment: Oh, I see I thought it was just Point.js and Line.js that had to be strict. Thanks for clarifying. I tried the proxy as well and it also didn't throw anything. That's the strangest part is that the end point initially has values but they become NaN as soon as it is assigned to this.end from what I can tell.

Comment: I even tried
`const endP = new Proxy(Point(ex, ey), {set() { throw new 
  Error('no') }});` and it had the correct values but NaN in the line

Answer (score -1):

What language is this?

Have you checked to see what happens if you remove const from the 3 lines? Not knowing this language, I'm at a disadvantage here.

I assume this is a language where you don't have to declare your function's parameters? In many languages, your header should be function line(Point start, Point end).

Why didn't you initialize this.end the same way you did this.start? That is:
    this.end= Point(end.x, end.y);

Comment: Hey sorry I should've been a bit more descriptive. This is Javascript and I had actually tried what you suggested earlier and it didn't work, and going back I thought maybe the end argument was being garbage collected and that's what made the values NaN but that didn't help either.

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer, but rather just comments.